# R: Select a cell when merging two data frames

Tags: r

I'm having some trouble when I try to merge two data frames. Here is an example:

```
Number <- c("1", "2", "3")
Letter <- factor(c("a", "b", "c"))

map <- data.frame(Number, Letter, row.names = c("Belgium", "Italy", "Senegal"))
```

This is my first data frame called "map", it looks like this:

```
       Number Letter
Belgium      1      a
Italy        2      b
Senegal      3      c
```

And if I try to select by row and column I don't have any problem:

```
map["Belgium", "Number"]
[1] "1"
```

Here I have my second data frame called "calendar":

```
Month <- c("January", "February", "March")

calendar <- data.frame(Month, row.names = c("Belgium", "Italy", "Senegal"))
```

It looks like this:

```
          Month
Belgium  January
Italy   February
Senegal    March
```

The problem comes when I try to merge both data frames:

```
map.amp = merge(map, calendar, by = 0)
    
    Row.names Number Letter    Month
 1   Belgium      1      a  January
 2     Italy      2      b February
 3   Senegal      3      c    March
```

Now, when I try to select a cell using rows and columns, the outcome is always NA

```
map.amp["Italy", "Month"]
[1] NA

map.amp["Belgium", "Number"]
[1] NA
```

How can I merge both data frames so I can keep using that kind of select function?

Comment: Related old post - [How does one merge dataframes by row name without adding a “Row.names” column?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17375849/496803)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to re-set the row names:

```
row.names(map.amp) <- map.amp$Row.names
```

Comment: It works! But when I print the data frame "map.amp" I get a duplicate row names, in two different columns. How could I prevent that?

Comment: Delete the extra column with `map.amp$Row.names <- NULL`

Answer (score 1):

```
map.amp[map.amp$Row.names =='Italy', 'Month']
```

Will work now as row.names is also a column now

Comment: That won't work, as you need to reference the data.frame name again - `map.amp[map.amp$Row.names =='Italy', 'Month']`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep using those row names you have to set the `Row.names` column back to row names. `tibble::column_to_rownames` is a nice option for this:

```
map.amp <- merge(map, calendar, by = 0) %>% tibble::column_to_rownames(var = "Row.names")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the answer in the comment by @thelatemail. Or use

```
subset(map.amp, Row.names =='Italy')[[ 'Month']]  # first get matching rows but them narrow to named column.
```

or

```
 subset(map.amp, Row.names =='Italy', 'Month')  # third argument is for column selection
```